# Simulating from normal copula in R with varying correlation matrices

Tags: r, simulation

I'm trying to simulate correlated normal copula realizations using the `copula` package in R. I have estimated the varying correlation matrices and stored them in an array with dimension 570x9x9: for each observation from 1 to 570, I have a 9x9 correlation matrix. Since the `normalCopula` command only requires a numeric vector as parameter, and not the entire correlation matrix, I "summarize" the correlation matrix using the command `P2p` which transforms the matrix into a vector (called `parameters`) with all 36 needed correlations. So far so good.

Now I want to start the simulation part. I thought about defining 570 different "static" normal copulas with each varying correlation structure, and then to simulate 5000 times from each of it using the `rCopula` function. More precisely:

```
mycop <- list()
for (i in 1:570){
mycop[i]=normalCopula(parameters[i,],dim=9,"un")
}

copula <- array(dim=c(570,9,5000))
for (i in 1:570){
  for (j in 1:5000){
    copula[i,,j]=rCopula(5000,mycop[i])[j,]
  }
}
```

Basically, for each i from 1 to 570 I simulate 5000 for 9 variables using `mycop[i]`, and store the results in the array `copula`.

However, this doesn't work because rCopula is supposed to have objects of `copula` class, whereas `mycop[i]` as defined is a list.

**QUESTION:** In what ways could I define the 570 copula specifications I need in such a way that I still have `copula` objects I can insert in the `rCopula`? What alternatives are there to `list()` to collect objects that are not numeric etc?

Comment: You need to store your elements **in** the list, not as the list. So use `mycop[[i]]<-`, note the double brackets. Also you can create a list-array with `copula <- array(list(),dim=c(570,9,5000))` and again use double brackets on `copula[[i,,j]]<-`. This isn't at all specific to `rCopula`, these are just basic list operations.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the suggestion. In fact this is the first time I'm working with lists, I wasn't aware of the double brackets thing. Now the only problem I have is that this takes a huge amount of time to simulate, I've run it for (i in 1:2), it's been 4 minutes and still hasn't finished. Whereas if I take rCopula(5000, mycop[[i]]) singularly for any i the results are immediate. You know what could be the cause for the code to be so slow?